# ValueError : cannot reshape array of size 224720 into shape (106,106,3)

Tags: python, numpy, нейронные-сети, tensorflow, keras

```
def define_discriminator(in_shape = (106, 106, 1)):
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Conv2D(64, (3,3), strides = (2,2), padding = "same", input_shape = in_shape))
    model.add(LeakyReLU(alpha = 0.2))
    model.add(Dropout(0.5))
    model.add(Conv2D(64, (3,3), strides = (2,2), padding = "same"))
    model.add(LeakyReLU(alpha = 0.2))
    model.add(Dropout(0.5))
    model.add(Flatten())
    model.add(Dense(1, activation = "sigmoid"))
    opt = Adam(learning_rate = 0.0002, beta_1 = 0.5)
    model.compile(loss = "binary_crossentropy", optimizer = opt, metrics = ["accuracy"])
    return model
def define_generator(latent_dim):
    model = Sequential()
    n_nodes = 128 * 53 * 53
    model.add(Dense(n_nodes, input_dim = latent_dim))
    model.add(LeakyReLU(alpha = 0.2))
    model.add(Reshape((53, 53, 128)))
    model.add(Dense(1024))
    model.add(Conv2DTranspose(1024, (4,4), strides = (2,2), padding = "same"))
    model.add(Dense(1024))
    model.add(LeakyReLU(alpha = 0.2))
    model.add(Dense(1024))
    model.add(Conv2D(1, (7,7), padding = "same", activation = "sigmoid"))
    return model
def define_gan(g_model, d_model):
    d_model.trianabel = False
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(g_model)
    model.add(d_model)
    opt = Adam(learning_rate = 0.0002, beta_1 = 0.5)
    model.compile(loss = "binary_crossentropy", optimizer = opt)
    return model
def generate_real_samples(dataset, n_samples):
    ix = randint(0, dataset.shape[0], n_samples)
    X = dataset[ix].T
    Y = ones((n_samples, 1)).T
    return X, Y

def generate_latent_points(latent_dim, n_samples):
    x_input = randn(latent_dim * n_samples)
    x_input = x_input.reshape(n_samples, latent_dim)
    return x_input

def generate_fake_samples(g_model, latent_dim, n_samples):
    x_input = generate_latent_points(latent_dim, n_samples)
    X = g_model.predict(x_input).T
    Y = zeros((n_samples, 1)).T
    return X, Y

    import tensorflow as tf
def train(g_model, d_model, gan_model, dataset, latent_dim, n_epochs=51, n_batch=10):
    bat_per_epo = int(dataset.shape[0] / n_batch)
    half_batch = int(n_batch / 2)
    for i in range(n_epochs):
        for j in range(bat_per_epo):
            X_real, y_real = generate_real_samples(dataset, half_batch)
            X_fake, y_fake = generate_fake_samples(g_model, latent_dim, half_batch)
            print(X_real, X_fake)
            print(y_real, y_fake)
            X = vstack((X_real, X_fake)).reshape(106, 106, 3)
            y = vstack((y_real, y_fake))
            print(X.shape)
            print(y.shape)
            d_loss, _ = d_model.train_on_batch(X.T, y.T)
            X_gan = generate_latent_points(latent_dim, n_batch)
            y_gan = ones((n_batch, 1))
            g_loss = gan_model.train_on_batch(X_gan, y_gan)
            print('>%d, %d/%d, d=%.3f, g=%.3f' % (i+1, j+1, bat_per_epo, d_loss, g_loss))
        if (i+1) % 10 == 0:
            summarize_performance(i, g_model, d_model, dataset, latent_dim)
            clear_output()
latent_dim = 100
d_model = define_discriminator()
g_model = define_generator(latent_dim)
gan_model = define_gan(g_model, d_model)
print(pixels.shape)
train(g_model, d_model, gan_model, np.array(pixels), latent_dim)
```

Код ошибки:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-233-b3360c520333> in <module>
      4 gan_model = define_gan(g_model, d_model)
      5 print(pixels.shape)
----> 6 train(g_model, d_model, gan_model, np.array(pixels), latent_dim)

<ipython-input-232-d0e3488c1736> in train(g_model, d_model, gan_model, dataset, latent_dim, n_epochs, n_batch)
      9             print(X_real, X_fake)
     10             print(y_real, y_fake)
---> 11             X = vstack((X_real, X_fake)).reshape(106, 106, 3)
     12             y = vstack((y_real, y_fake))
     13             print(X.shape)

ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 224720 into shape (106,106,3)
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста как решить эту проблему? Если нужно могу приложить Jupyter Notebook и папку с файлами(там изображения).
Первоисточник кода:
https://towardsdatascience.com/bachgan-using-gans-to-generate-original-baroque-music-10c521d39e52

Comment: Напечатайте какая `shape` у `X_real` и `X_fake` перед этим. Почему вы именно к указанным размерам приводите? Что-то тут не так.

Comment: @CrazyElf 4, 106, 106, 5

Comment: Ну вот никак оно в (106, 106, 3) не поместится, да. Может не надо вообще решейпить? Или надо, но в другое.

Comment: Изначально и не нужно было. Изначально одна матрица была размера(5, 106, 106, 3), но из-за того, что другая была размером (5, 106, 106, 1), мне пришлось транспонировать 2, для того, чтобы их объединить, и после этого мне выдало следующее: Input 0 of layer sequential_231 is incompatible with the layer: expected axis -1 of input shape to have value 1 but received input with shape (5, 106, 106, 4) и я начал танцы с бубном, что решить это.

Comment: Как я понимаю модель не может принять матрицу такого размера, но как мне изменить ее, чтобы все заработало?

Comment: Я так сразу не соображу, размеры слоёв в нейросетях - это думать нужно. Вы хоть напишите - что вы вообще обрабатываете? Картинки? Только получается часть чёрно-белые судя по размерности, часть цветные, а часть цветные с альфа-каналом, насколько я понимаю. Это не взлетит в таком виде просто от решейпа никак, я думаю, должен быть какой-то один формат картинок, иначе нейросеть запутается.

Comment: https://towardsdatascience.com/bachgan-using-gans-to-generate-original-baroque-music-10c521d39e52 Вот здесь весь код и объяснение модели, так будет проще.

Comment: @CrazyElf Спасибо большое за то, что пытались мне помочь в этом вопросе, вы такой единственный. Я решил проблему просто превратив свои изображения в серый цвет, проблема была именно там.

Comment: О, ну отлично, что разобрались. Можете оформить тогда свой ответ: вкратце в чём была суть и кусок кода, который делает нужное преобразование.